# Execute Program until specific amount of bytes has been returned on stdout, then terminate

Tags: shell, stdout, byte

Imagine I have the following program/script `./generate-infinite-byte-stream`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo -n 'hello'
sleep infinity
```

The infinite sleep command represents a network connection that may or may not deliver more data in the indefinite future that I am not interested in.

I would like to have a program, let's call it `take 5` that runs `./generate-infinite-byte-stream` until it has output 5 bytes on stdout and then terminates it:

```bsh
take 5 ./generate-infinite-byte-stream
# gives 'hello' and returns with exit code 0
```

Is there such a program or do I need to roll my own with popen()? The program `take` should also redirect stdin to the executed program.

Note: `head -c 5` does not do the right thing, because it does not terminate:

```bsh
./generate-infinite-byte-stream | head -c 5
# this returns 'hello', but never terminates
```

Aside: The name Take is inspired by the https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Take.html command which returns the first n elements of a list.

Comment: That script is very poorly named.  If it really did produce more output, then it would be terminated by trying to write to a closed pipe.

Comment: @TobySpeight You mean the `./generate-infinite-byte-stream` script? That's fine. You could even imagine that it said `echo hello; sleep 1; echo world; sleep infinity`. I do not care about the extra output after the first 5 bytes and I want to completely ignore any errors that might occur and terminate that program/script as soon as possible after the first 5 bytes have been returned, ignoring all the rest.

Comment: I don't know of a program that does what you want - it's usually sufficient to close the stream, meaning that the 6th byte of output will kill the producer with `SIGPIPE`.  To terminate the producer immediately after byte 5, rather than at byte 6, will likely require a simple program.

Answer (score 1):

If your shell is Bash, you could use a process substitution.  Demo:

```
dd bs=1 count=5 < <(printf hello; sleep infinity)
```

That doesn't kill the producer, but does disconnect it so that the `dd` command completes.  This may or may not be what you need.

Comment: Thank you, that already helps as a starting point. But I will need a solution that kills the producer, otherwise the system will get littered with open network connections waiting for irrelevant data and lots of running processes.

Comment: Yes, then you'll need to write a small program to signal the writer when you've read enough.